# Debtor owes me, trying to figure out how to freeze RBC account

Tags: canada, assets

Through the summer, I picked up a client on a contract basis for whom I completed about 3 months of work. I had every reason to believe they would come good in terms of paying me, as the owners of the company are associated with other reputable firms. After not having gotten paid and having gotten a ton of excuses and even some bullying, I decided to sue the corporation in Alberta small claims. I won default judgement as they didn't file a response.

With the judgement in hand, and the knowledge that they have a bank account with RBC, I am trying to figure out my next move. There are about ~100 RBC branches in Calgary and trying to narrow down their home branch won't be trivial. I know RBC has a main branch in Calgary - but I am seeing conflicting information about whether they can help me out.

I am also trying to figure out their clients that may owe them money to try to garnish that way. Does anyone have any experience or suggestions they can share that would help me?

Comment: Is the "wage-garnishing" tag accurate given this seems to be about claiming money from a company rather than an individual?

Comment: Did you g back to review your information you received from the court? In my US county they have a process to follow if the losing party refuses to pay.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be a matter of law rather than personal finance.

Comment: What does the judgement say? Did it order RBC to freeze the client's bank account? If so, I assume you can just walk into any RBC and ask them what to do. RBC would presumably be required to help you with this.